# Letter Equations: if '7 D of the W' means '7 Days of the Week', what do the following mean?

Tags: logical-deduction, letters

[image]

Transcription:

```
LETTER EQUATIONS

1. 8 B in a B
2. 6 B in an O
3. 8 T on an O
4. 5 V in the A
5. 18 H in a GC
6. 12 S of the Z
7. 8 P in the SS
8. 6 IS on the G
9. 64 S on a CB
10. 7 N of the MS
11. 1000 Y in a M
12. 18 LE in this P
13. 7 B in the HPS
14. 24 S in the AC
15. 13 S in the USF
16. SW and the 7 D
17. 25 PN under 100
18. 23 P of C in the HB

SHIVANSH SHARMA
```

Many of these are quite common. Some others I've added on my own which you'll not find anywhere on the internet.
For any clarification, comment down below.

Comment: why use a picture of words?

Comment: Is there a reason you put your puzzles into images? This makes them less accessible.

Comment: I think these "letter equations" are commonly known as [Ditloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditloid) in reference to the clue 1 D in the L of ID.

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer 17/18

Tojrah has now gotten the other one in their answer

> 1. 8 Bits in a Byte
>  2. 6 Balls in an Over (Cricket)
>  3. 8 Tentacles on an Octopus
>  4. 5 Vowel in the Alphabet
>  5. 18 Holes in a Golf Course
>  6. 12 Signs of the Zodiac
>  7. 8 Planets in the Solar System
>  8. **see Tojrah's answer**
>  9. 64 Squares on a Chessboard.
>  10. 7 Notes of the Music Scale.
>  11. 1000 Years in a Millenium
>  12. 18 Letter Equations in the Puzzle
>  13. 7 Books in the Harry Potter Series
>  14. 24 Spokes in the [Ashok Chakra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashoka_Chakra)
>  15. 13 Stripes in the United States Flag
>  16. Snow White and the 7 Dwarves
>  17. 25 Prime Numbers under 100
>  18. 23 Pairs of Chromosome in the Human Body

Comment: good job. The 8th one is a bit tricky.

Comment: 3. 8 triangles on an octahedron

Comment: @FlorianF Yep, that works too, I suspect there will be more here obtained by pairing 8 with the prefix "octo/octa"

Comment: 6 indigenous species on the Galapagos? Dunno, just guessing here.

Comment: @PrimeMover Interesting, do you have a reference for that number? I cannot find it

Comment: @hexomino Nope, not at all. As I say, a complete guess.

Answer (score 6):

The others ones already guessed, @hexomino my guess for the 8th:

> 6 Infinity Stones on the Gauntlet